# Ito's Lemma - Stochastic differential equation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

**Question.** Apply Ito's formula to calculate the stochastic differential of:

$X_t = e^{at} \cos(b W_t)$

Determine for which values of $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ the process $X_t$ is a martingale.

**Attempt** Set $W_t = x$ and applied Itô's formula. I calculate the partial derivatives:

$$\begin{align*}
F(t,x) &= e^{at} \cos(bx)\\
\partial_t F(t,x) &= a F(t,x) \\
\partial_x F(t,x) &= b e^{at} (- \sin(bx)) \\
\partial_{xx} F(t,x) &= b^2 e^{at}  (-\cos(bx))
\end{align*}$$

The SDE is:

$$dX_t = ae^{at} \cos(bx) dt + be^{at} (-\sin(bx)) dW_t - \frac{1}{2} b^2 e^{at} \cos(bx) dt$$

$$dX_t = e^{at} \cos(bx) (a - \frac{1}{2} b^2) dt - be^{at} \sin(bx) dW_t$$

How do I then calculate the values of $a$ and $b$ for which $X_t$ is a martingale?

Comment: a necessary condition for an Itô process to be a martingale is that the drift (i.e. the term associated with $dt$) must vanish.

Comment: Hi Chaos, if I understand a-$\frac{1}{2}$$b^2$ = 0, a=$\frac{1}{2}$$b^2$. It's correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Correct. In the last two equations you should put back $W_t$ for $x$.

Comment: stochastic differential result: d$X_t$ = $e^{at}$ cos(b$W_t$) (a-$\frac{1}{2})$$dt$ - b$e^{at}$ sen(b$W_t$)d$W_t$ and this process is a martingale for a=$\frac{1}{2}$ $b^2$.